# Is there a standard exception to be thrown if object is not instance of something in java?

Tags: java, exception, interface

Let's say I have the following:

```
public interface Foo {
    ...
}

public class Gin {
    ...
}

public class Fizz {
    ...
}

public class Buzz {
    public Foo getAFoo() {
        ...
    }

    public void test() {
        Foo myfoo = getAFoo();
        if (myFoo instanceof Bar) {
            Bar myBar = (Bar) myFoo;
            //do something more
        } else {
        //throw new something exception
        }
    }
}
```

Is this reasonable programming? Is there a built-in exception that test() can throw or should I create my own exception class for this?

Comment: Some `IllegalStateException`, perhaps.

Comment: Since there are plenty of possibilities to reduce the risk of wrong types using interfaces and generics i would prefer having an own Exception in this case to be able to better describe the "business case" of what went wrong in the else-part. But it is realy just my 2cents to this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although somewhat opinion-based, the usual exception to throw when an object is not the expected type is [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html), and this approach is used fairly widely in the JDK. You could go one better than the JDK though and provide a message:

```
throw new ClassCastException("Object was not of type Bar");
```

If the object was passed as a parameter, you can use [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), also with a message :

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("myParameter was not of type Bar");
```

Comment: Why an Illegal "Argument" exception?

Comment: @Aditya "Argument" is the mathematical term for "parameter". In this context, it has nothing to do with "fighting with words"

Comment: I know that. But this is about casting a `Foo` instance to `Bar`. `ClassCastException` is acceptable. But I don't think this is related to argument! You can pass the same message as a parameter in a `ClassCastException` instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was confused by the description:

_thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance_

In this case the exception is not about the attempted cast, rather the type itself.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question:

Is this reasonable programming?
You have an opportunity to make use of Strategy pattern as described http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm.

It will remove your need for if and else checking, instead you inject appropriate type of object (implementing same interface) and call respective method. It will also ensure you wont need to change you code with another if else block basically following open for extension closed for modification.

Regarding exception if you want to stick with code above you could throw IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: this post is flagged as low quality answer. please provide some explanation.

Comment: What do you mean by low quality?

Comment: it means you just have a link which will may be expired and your answer is not informative, so please improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a compile time error.

You'll get something like:

```
error: incompatible types: Bar cannot be converted to Foo
```

Because `interface Foo` does not `extend` from `Bar`

So there is no question about throwing an exception for it.

But still if you just **IMAGINE** any such thing to be legal in `Java`, you must create a custom exception. Coz there is no such inbuilt exception class dedicated for such errors.

Comment: It is. I tried that. Create an interface named Foo and another interface Bar. Create a class that creates an object of interface of Foo as `Foo foo = new Foo(){}` and try to cast it to Bar like `Bar bar = (Bar)foo`. It will cry at compilation.